# conan packages not found in Github Actions

Tags: c++, cmake, github-actions, conan

This configurations works locally on Linux machines, but not on Github Action's Ubuntu runner. I get a `find_package` error.

## conanfile.txt

```
[requires]
docopt.cpp/0.6.3
sqlite3/3.36.0

[generators]
cmake
```

## CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
set(This weighterm)
project(${This} VERSION 0.1)

include(${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/conanbuildinfo.cmake)
conan_basic_setup()

include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR})

find_package(docopt COMPONENTS CXX REQUIRED)
find_package(SQLite3)

set(SOURCES
        src/weighterm_data_sqlite.cpp
        src/weight_measure.cpp
        src/weighterm.cpp
        src/weighterm_cli.cpp
    )

add_executable(${This} ${SOURCES})
target_link_libraries(${This} ${CONAN_LIBS})
```

## cmake.yml (relevant parts)

```
env:
  BUILD_TYPE: Release
jobs:
  job:
    name: ${{ matrix.os }}-build
    runs-on: ${{ matrix.os }}
    strategy:
      fail-fast: false
      matrix:
        include:
          - os: ubuntu-latest
            output-path: "build/weighterm/bin"
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    
    - name: Install dependencies with conan
      shell: bash
      run: |
        mkdir build
        cd build
        pip install conan
        conan install .. --build missing
    - name: Configure CMake
      run: cmake -B ${{github.workspace}}/build -S . -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=${{env.BUILD_TYPE}}

    - name: Build
      run: cmake --build ${{github.workspace}}/build --config ${{env.BUILD_TYPE}}
```

## Output

```
-- Current conanbuildinfo.cmake directory: /home/runner/work/weighterm/weighterm/build
-- Conan: Compiler GCC>=5, checking major version 9
-- Conan: Checking correct version: 9
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:13 (find_package):
  By not providing "Finddocopt.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "docopt", but
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "docopt" with any
  of the following names:

    docoptConfig.cmake
    docopt-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "docopt" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "docopt_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "docopt"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed.
```

Comment: I'm not sure how your build is working locally, to use `find_pacakage` you need to use the [find_pacakge generator](https://docs.conan.io/en/1.4/integrations/cmake/cmake_find_package_generator.html). It's much simpler to just use [targets](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/integrations/build_system/cmake/cmake_generator.html#targets-approach) though

Comment: Actually, the latest recommended generator is ``CMakeDeps``: https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/reference/conanfile/tools/cmake.html. It is experimental, but already more powerful and flexible than the others, and it is the one that will be continued in Conan 2.0